# Count of second dimension in two dimension data in Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I have the data in this format

```
(apple, laptop)
(apple, laptop)
(apple, ipad)
(dell, laptop)
```

I want to output to be

```
(apple, laptop, 2)
(apple, ipad, 1)
(dell, laptop, 1)
```

I wanted to do this using `groupby and then count` but groupby is not allowing grouping based on two columns.

I am new to Spark and lack of ideas. Could someone please help?

Comment: You could just use countByValue API .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want the count for each data then you could just use countByValue API.

```
val data = Array(("apple","laptop"),("apple","laptop"),("dell","laptop"), ("apple","ipad"))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(data)
scala> rdd.countByValue
res0: scala.collection.Map[(String, String),Long] = Map((apple,laptop) -> 2, (apple,ipad) -> 1, (dell,laptop) -> 1)
```

Comment: Spot on. I didn't know countByValue works on multiple dimensions as well.